Repeating textures in segments around z axis of a sphere
How do I repeat a square texture in increasing amounts of segments around the z axis of a sphere, as below in the video. The video uses a gradient texture but how do I get it to work with a square texture?



Could you at least show some example or sketch or whatever your goal is? How should the square repeat in increasing amounts around the Z axis?

Also do you mean square as in a 2D plane or a cube?

Extra info added to question.

Whatever transformation you applied to color, you can apply to the texture coordinate:


Use the polar or spherical coordinate systems and adopt them to your case.
GLSL:
vec2 cartesian_to_polar(vec2 cartesian) {

    float radius = length(cartesian);
    float angle = atan(cartesian.y, cartesian.x);

    return vec2(angle, radius);
}

vec3 cartesian_to_spherical(vec3 cartesian) {

    float radius = length(cartesian);
    float theta = atan(cartesian.y, cartesian.x);
    float phi = acos(cartesian.z / radius);

    return vec3(radius, theta, phi);
}

Blender:

